# LPR on Windows: Can you specify # of copies?

Tags: windows, printing, lpr

In Linux, you can use

**lpr -#5 foo.txt**

to get 5 copies of a document when sending to an LPD-based print server.

The Windows (XP, 2003, 2008) version of LPR supplied by MS doesn't seem to have this option, though.

Does anyone know if there's a hidden option to specify the number of copies?

Thanks.

Comment: I need to go read the specs, but I think LPD handles or is passed the # of copies, LPR doesn't queue 5 copies.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not:

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/lpr.mspx?mfr=true

Well at least not according to the official Microsoft documentation.

Comment: Thanks.  For what it's worth, I discovered www.intelliscribe.net offers a Windows-based lpr client that has more features.  Costs about $200-$300, though.  Some things are just better in Linux. The command line printing options in Windows are not great.

Answer (score 0):

This is gonna suck as an answer, because I haven't tried or tested it.. but can you install cygwin then use the linux lpr?

Answer (score 0):

Use the LPR command line approach to add files to the print queue. Follow the example closely with regard to spacing and case. You can enter additional file names, or option switches followed by file names, if necessary.

Enter the following command at the MS-DOS prompt. Follow the example closely with regard to spacing and case.

```
LPR -S<server> -P<printer> [-options] <print file name>, <copies>
```

TipFor example, use the LPR command to print five copies of the plot file test.txt from the 999.9.999.9 network address to printer1: `LPR -S999.9.999.9 -Pprinter1 -Og test.txt,5`.

Source :

http://www.barrcentral.com/help/beps/Using_the_LPR_command_line_approach.htm